# Observers in view controllers from Bluetooth singleton class in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, singleton, core-bluetooth

I have created a singleton class to interact with multiple view controllers. How do I notify about the Bluetooth state from a singleton class?

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth
        
class MyBluetoothManager: CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate{
       
        static let shared = MyBluetoothManager()
        
        let central = CBCentralManager(delegate: MyCentralManagerDelegate.shared,
                                       queue: nil, options: nil)
}
```

I will be implementing delegates of CBPeripheral in the future. Suggest me if there any existing blog or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider `NotificationCenter`.

In your view controllers you need to add observer for your custom type of notification. E.g.:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver( self, selector: #selector( self.methodtohandle ), name: .yourcustomeventname, object: nil )
```

don't forget to remove the observer when the controller is no longer needed/presented:

```
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .yourcustomeventname, object: nil)
```

and on your singleton class you would call "post":

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .yourcustomeventname, object: somedata)
```

Comment: I did that @DimaG. I am in search of a more relevant answer. I don't think it is the only way to get notified by delegates. By the way, thanks because I can come to know about how to remove a target observer.

Comment: Thats up to you of course. Based on your code, I assumed that your 'MyBluetoothManager' will implement delegates protocols and then you need to communicate data to view controllers. For this scenario NotificationCenter is great because it keeps ViewControllers and your singleton loosely coupled.  There is a way to do it with callbacks, but then you are risking to get memory leaks.

Comment: Thanks. Currently, I am going with your solution. It's working indeed.